# Uniform limit of analytic function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

For the following theorem and it's proof:  https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniform_Limit_of_Analytic_Functions_is_Analytic, I am not fully convinced. The last sentence concludes "uniformly in each compact disk contained in $U$". But a compact subset $K$ need not be a compact disk. What do I miss?

Comment: I haven't looked at that Wikipedia page, but it sounds like at least possibly what you missed is that if a function defined in $\Omega$ is analytic in each disk contained in $\Omega$ then it is analytic in $\Omega$.

Comment: The first line says "By [Equivalence of Local Uniform Convergence and Compact Convergence](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Local_Uniform_Convergence_and_Compact_Convergence)" which means/implies that a point-wise convergent sequence $f_n$ of analytic functions converges to $f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $U$ if and only if there exists a covering $\{D_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\mathfrak A}$ of $U$ made of (compact) disks such that for all $\alpha\in\mathfrak A$, $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $D_\alpha$.

Comment: Missed that first line, got my answer!